# Inverse Label Encoding for plotting purposes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a feature in a DataFrame encoded with integers, i.e., int64 type. Further, I have a dictionary with the equivalent classes. Is there a way to draw a bar plot for this feature with the original categories?

df = pd.DataFrame({"feature_1": [-1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]})

tags = {"Good": 1, "Bad": 0, "Indiferent":-1}

I would like to obtain a pie chart with relative frequency (expressed %) of every case, with the string labels contained in the dictionary.

Comment: Please, provide an excerpt of your data and the result you want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. Just have to manipulate the df to replace the values for the words you want, then get the count.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({"feature_1": [-1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]})
tags = {"Good": 1, "Bad": 0, "Indiferent":-1}


df = df['feature_1'].replace({v:k for k,v in tags.items()})\
                    .value_counts()\
                    .reset_index()\
                    .rename(columns = {'index': 'feature_1','feature_1':'count'})

sns.catplot(x = "feature_1", y = 'count', data = df, kind = 'bar')
```

[image]